# Determine weibull parameters through sampled data in Python using fmin

Tags: scipy, data-fitting, weibull

I want to determine the parameters a,b and c of the Weibull function mentioned below using fmin for the sampled data x.

```
x= np.array([1.79, 2.04, 2.42, 2.19, 1.75, 1.59, 1.63, 1.69, 1.6 , 1.68, 1.86,
       1.99, 1.88, 1.37, 1.96, 2.71, 2.5 , 1.71, 1.53, 2.65])

def fitweibull(x):
    def optfun(theta):
       return np.exp(-((x-theta[0])/theta[1])**theta[2])
    # initial guesses: 
    a = 1
    b = 1 
    c = 1
    return fmin(optfun, [a,b,c],xtol=0.01,ftol=0.01,disp=0)

fitweibull(x)
```

It gives me the error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

First question: What do I do wrong? Second question: Is there a way to improve the accuracy of the solution by defining a better starting point for a,b,c?

I am not interested in built-in scipy function to determine weibull fits unless it is used to  validate results.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'd say the whole idea of fitting it like this is wrong. The detailed error message is due to the fact the `fmin` expects a function that returns a single value.

Comment: Yes, that would be a single value for a, b and c (is theta[0], theta[1], theta[2]. See for example: https://gist.github.com/plasmaman/5508278

Comment: ...have you seen the `-np.log( np.sum( ... )  )` for the log likelihood?

Comment: The whole point is that i want to fit to a custom function. Not built-in scipy.

Comment: The whole point of my comments is that this is independent of your errors. The link you put minimizes the loglikelyhood. Therefore, it takes the log of the function and sums over it. This is maximized by minimizing the negative. As `x` is an `np.array` your `optfun` return an array. For `fmin` to work you need to return a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate that you are seeking a custom function and to avoid using scipy, however the custom function you presented is not the best way to do this.
I recommend you use the library [reliability](https://reliability.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It uses maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) to find the solution. In your example presented above, you are looking to fit a 3 parameter Weibull distribution. This can be done in reliability as follows:

```
from reliability.Fitters import Fit_Weibull_3P
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1.79, 2.04, 2.42, 2.19, 1.75, 1.59, 1.63, 1.69, 1.6 , 1.68, 1.86, 1.99, 1.88, 1.37, 1.96, 2.71, 2.5 , 1.71, 1.53, 2.65]
Fit_Weibull_3P(failures=x)
plt.show()
```

Results:

```
Results from Fit_Weibull_3P (95% CI):
Analysis method: Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE)
Failures / Right censored: 20/0 (0% right censored) 

Parameter  Point Estimate  Standard Error  Lower CI  Upper CI
    Alpha        0.660176        0.096205  0.496155   0.87842
     Beta         1.61525        0.282976   1.14583     2.277
    Gamma         1.33523       0.0596597   1.22327   1.45743 

Goodness of fit    Value
 Log-likelihood -6.52595
           AICc  20.5519
            BIC  22.0391
             AD 0.937743
```

[image: probability plot]